# Can I include code in .mobi to control the native voice synthesizer in a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, text-to-speech

Some kindle models come with a text to speech software that has several [optional settings](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/let-your-kindle-read-to-you-with-texttospeech.html).  There is both male and female, as well as 3 speeds, which gives 6 different combinations.

In theory, a low budget writer could create a complete audio book using only synthetic voices, 3 male & 3 female.  It would have the advantage of the smaller file size of a text book, but still allow for distinct character voices.

For this to work, there would need to be code in the book that switched between the 6 optional native voices.  Assuming the user has activated the text to speech speech.

What (*if any*) code could I include a .mobi file that would control the native voice synthesizer?

Comment: EPUB3 allows (in theory) to use CSS 3 Speech ( http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/tts/speech.php ), so my best guess is that Amazon might have something similar; however, there is no trace of it in the official Kindle Guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in any of kindle eBook formats. Amazon is stripping all html which is not supported as they stated it in [Kindle Publishing Guidelines](http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf). Also you don't have access to any of device settings - including Text to Speak.